# node.js custom events: Cannot call method 'emit' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

I'm learning node, its events API and trying to make a simple example.

So here's my code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var util = require('util');
var events = require('events');
var FileLoader = function () {
    events.EventEmitter.call(this);
    this.load = function (url) {
        fs.readFile(url, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
             } else {
                this.emit('loaded', data.toString());
            }
        });
    };
};
util.inherits(FileLoader, events.EventEmitter);
module.exports = FileLoader;
```

And I want to `load()` a text file and when it is loaded, catch it with `.on('loaded',function(){...})`, but `this` is undefined, so program crashes.

I'm definitely missing something, how to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an issue with Node, it is an issue with JavaScript. The `this` in `this.emit` is not a `FileLoader` instance.

I recommend you read up on the behavior of `this` in JavaScript. The [MDN docs for `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) may be helpful for you.

In this case, you need to bind the `this` inside your `readFile` callback so that the inner `this` is the outer `this` by adding `.bind(this)` to your callback.

```
this.load = function (url) {
    fs.readFile(url, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
         } else {
            this.emit('loaded', data.toString());
        }
    }.bind(this));
};
```

Comment: I suspected that _`this` in `this.emit` is not a `FileLoader` instance_, and needed a way to pass `this` into callback. `bind()` is the way I was looking for, thanks.